# Stuttering when Drawing to Image in GCD Block

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, core-animation, grand-central-dispatch

I have the following method which takes some `CAShapeLayers` and converts them into a `UIImage`. The `UIImage` is used in a cell for a `UITableView` (much like the photos app when you select a photo from one of your libraries). This method is called from within a `GCD` block:

```
-(UIImage*) imageAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{
    Graphic *graphic = [[Graphic graphicWithType:index]retain];

    CALayer *layer = [[CALayer alloc] init];
    layer.bounds = CGRectMake(0,0, graphic.size.width, graphic.size.height);
    layer.shouldRasterize = YES;
    layer.anchorPoint = CGPointZero;
    layer.position = CGPointMake(0, 0);

    for (int i = 0; i < [graphic.shapeLayers count]; i++)
    {
        [layer addSublayer:[graphic.shapeLayers objectAtIndex:i]];
    }

    CGFloat largestDimension = MAX(graphic.size.width, graphic.size.height);
    CGFloat maxDimension = self.thumbnailDimension;
    CGFloat multiplicationFactor = maxDimension / largestDimension;
    CGSize graphicThumbnailSize = CGSizeMake(multiplicationFactor * graphic.size.width, multiplicationFactor * graphic.size.height);

    layer.sublayerTransform = CATransform3DScale(layer.sublayerTransform, graphicThumbnailSize.width / graphic.size.width, graphicThumbnailSize.height / graphic.size.height, 1);
    layer.bounds = CGRectMake(0,0, graphicThumbnailSize.width, graphicThumbnailSize.height);

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(layer.bounds.size, NO, 0);
    [layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *image = [UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext() retain];
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    [layer release];
    [graphic release];

    return [image autorelease];
}
```

For whatever reason, when I'm scrolling the `UITableView` and loading the images in, it is stuttering a little bit. I know the `GCD` code is fine because it's worked previously so it appears something in this code is causing the stuttering. Does anyone know what that could be? Is `CAAnimation` not thread safe? Or does anyone know a better way to take a bunch of `CAShapeLayers` and convert them into a `UIImage`?

Comment: Did you check the framerate using Instruments. Also when you say, you are using GCD, are you running the whole thing on an asynchronous queue. I am sure you are. Also when you say stuttering, can you please elaborate what you are seeing, is it for new cells which are coming into view ...

Comment: @Srikanth - Yes, the frame rate when images are loading into the table is 35-40. However after I've cached them, it's 60. Yes, it is on an asynchronous queue. By stuttering I mean when I scroll the tableview as fast I can and the scrolling won't be smooth, it'll kind of be stop and go (presumably to do loading).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I believe:

```
[layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
```

Cannot be done on a separate thread, so I had to do the following:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imageSize, NO, 0);
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
//draw the mutable paths of the CAShapeLayers to the context
UIImage *image = [UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext() retain];
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

There is a great example of this (where I learned to do it) in the [WWDC2012](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/) video "Building Concurrent User Interfaces on iOS"